# iperf3 not working despite allowing port in firewall

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I want to test the network speed from my home network because it's taking 16 seconds to download a 1MB file:

[image]

I tried running iperf3 -s -p 5201 in the VM and allowed ingress on the same port in the Firewall Google Cloud page. I also allowed the port in Linux UFW.

However, when running iperf3 -c  on my PC, it doesn't connect. I tried to do iperf to another network from my PC and it worked.

Are there other settings I need to adjust in GC?

Comment: You have left lots of details out of your question. Edit your question and include the following: 1) How fast is your internet connection? 2) What is the compute engine machine type? 3) Show the firewall rule. 4) Show the iperf command that you are running locally and the error message. 5) Are you connecting to the public external IP address? 6) Can you connect to a public iperf server?

Comment: While running iperf3 test, make sure that you are using the same iperf3 version on both server and client side. I ran the iperf3 test between my local terminal and VM instance and it's working.While configuring firewall rules, please ensure that traffic direction is ingress and the allowed port should be TCP:5201;UDP:5201 and TCP:22.